# Facebook Likebox Stream not displaying photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

After some extensive web searching, it appears others are having my same or a similar problem. But I have been unable to find any sort of solution.

I have 3 different clients for whom I've added Facebook Likebox widgets to their sites. I haven't had any issues for over 2 years. Last week though, without any changes to site, 90% of photos stopped showing in the Likebox Stream on all sites. The only thing that *is* showing on their Stream is comment, day, & time of post (photo upload).

Went to Facebook Developer site to address the problem (recreate code in case of changes) and even on FB Developer Page where Likebox code is created for copy & paste to site, the preview pane of widget isn't showing pictures either.

The oddest part is that there doesn't seem to be any common element to which photos *do* show. For example, one site is showing 2 photos out of the 12 most recent photo uploads, all of which were uploaded to timeline from the same pc.

What was once a perfect solution allowing tech-challenged site owners some content control, saving me time, saving them money, and cross promoting their sites with their Facebook pages, has now just turned into a nightmare.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I have been having the same issue. Someone else posted something about keeping the picture size smaller then 300 pixels or so which did make it work again. However what does that do for people like me doing mobile uploads or all the pictures were already posted. Well a glimmer of hope that they are working on something is when using a pc signed on as an admin the settings menu has been changed all around. So hopefully this is temporary.

Comment: I had the same issue since few days. I think Facebook developers did something wrong. i hope it is temporarily too.

Comment: Same problem here. The images are loaded correctly but not showing in the stream. When i erase the class "photoWrap" from DIV CSS class that contains the IMG element the image appears correctly. The complete class name of the DIV element is "_46-h photoWrap"

Comment: I'm using FB's iframe code, which code are you using?

Comment: Did anyone here file a bug report in Facebook's bug tracker?

Comment: Problem still exists.  Has anyone found a solution beyond making image smaller? I have filed bug reports to Facebook multiple times.

Comment: Apparently Facebook is aware of the issue, looking into it, and the bug has been "assigned" with a "medium" priority as of 07/23 https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/181170558724402?browse=external_tasks_search_results_52348c77d0e635988054809